# How can I specify lifetimes in associated types?

Tags: syntax, rust, traits, lifetime, associated-types

I'm trying to get each `GraphicsContext` implementation to return a different implementation of `Shader`.

```rust
pub trait Resources {
    type Shader: shader::Shader;
}

pub trait GraphicsContext {

    type Resources: Resources;

    /// Creates a shader object
    fn create_shader<'a>(&'a self, shader::Stage, source: &str)
        -> Result<<<Self as GraphicsContext>::Resources as Resources>::Shader,
                  shader::CreateError>;

    /// Creates a shader program object
    fn create_shader_program<'a>(&'a self, shaders: Vec<&shader::Shader>)
        -> Result<Box<shader::ShaderProgram + 'a>, shader::ProgramCreateError>;

    // more to come

}
```

This is so that the `create_shader_program` method (and other methods) know the concrete type of `Shader` so that they can call implementation specific methods on the shader object.

I don't want to put these methods (such as `setCurrent` or `attach`) into a trait that all implementations must use. Not all graphics APIs use the same system: OpenGL is bind/unbind, Vulkan will be structs/set fields, DirectX is something else etc.

**Firstly, I ask is this the right way to structure my engine.** I believe that in my framework/application level code that require these `Shader` objects, I can specify the concrete type based upon the current type of the `Context`.

```rust
// almost certain this doesn't compile, but should be possible in theory
// I'm trying to say:
// the type of the `shader` argument must match to the associated type
// contained within the `context`
fn do_something_with_shader(context: &GraphicsContext,
                            shader: ??**GraphicsContext::Resources::Shader**??)
                           -> Result<Foo, Bar>;
```

or perhaps:

```rust
fn do_something_with_shader<T>(context: &GraphicsContext<T>,
                               shader: ??**T::Shader**??)
    where T: GraphicsContext::Resources -> Result<Foo, Bar>;
```

Is something like this possible? Hopefully you can see I sort of understand the basic generics (I come from Java), but this is driving me insane (it does feel *very* hackish).

If that is the right way to go, then there comes a problem with my implementation. `rustc` wants the associated type to have a lifetime specified.

```
wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
opal_driver_gl/src/context.rs:23     type Shader = Shader;
```

My `OpenGLShader` struct is actually of type `OpenGLShader<'a>`, so the error makes sense. My question is where do I get the lifetime from in this bunch of code:

```rust
struct OpenGLResources;

impl Resources for OpenGLResources {
    type Shader = OpenGLShader;
}

impl GraphicsContext for OpenGLGraphicsContext {

    type Resources = Resources;

    /// Creates a shader object
    fn create_shader<'a>(&'a self, stage: core_shader::Stage, source: &str)
        -> Result<<<Self as GraphicsContext>::Resources as Resources>::Shader,
                  core_shader::CreateError> {
       // impl goes here
    }

}
```

I tried attaching a lifetime to `OpenGLResources` and `OpenGLGraphicsContext`, which solved the error but then said `error: parameter 'a is never used`.

So **secondly, I ask how I can include that lifetime inside my associated type**.

Thanks so much if you can take a look at this. I feel that something like this must be possible to be checked at compile time but I'm pretty new to Rust so I just can't quite grok how to implement it.

Comment: Please split your question in two. Currently it contains two questions which are only marginally related, with the first one likely being unfit for Stackoverflow.

Comment: For the second question - it would require associated types to have lifetime parameters: `type Shader<'a> = OpenGLShader<'a>`. This feature is known as higher-kinded types and it is not yet available in Rust. I'm not writing this as an answer now because of the reason in the above comment.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I was considering just asking the first question, but then i thought that the second wouldn't matter if my 'abstract' idea was flawed, so I included it. I you want I'll get rid of it.

Comment: As for the second comment, it sounds like I'm trying to achieve the impossible then. However could i turn `OpenGLGraphicsContext` into `OpenGLGraphicsContext<'f>` and specify the lifetime for `Resources` as `Resources<'f>` and then write  `type Shader = OpenGLShader<'f>`?

Comment: Yes, I think you can, because methods in your trait do not use `'a`. You just need to be careful about handling lifetimes in the `OpenGLGraphicsContext` itself - you would probably need to use [`PhantomData`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html). It is not possible to do in general, though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to generics, which provided a successful implementation.

Given the `Resources<'a>`, I can define `GraphicsContext` like so:

```
trait GraphicsContext<'a, R: Resources<'a>>
```

The 2 `'a` lifetimes above are needed for the `Shader<'a>` and `ShaderProgram<'a>` structs inside `Resources`

Then the OpenGL implementation can be provided. Note that `Resources` has been changed to `OpenGLResources`.

```
                             // replaced here
impl<'a> GraphicsContext<'a, OpenGLResources<'a>> for OpenGLGraphicsContext<'a> {

    fn create_shader(&'a self, ty: Type, source: &str) -> Result<Shader<'a>, ShaderCreationError> {
        // do something
    }

}
```